# Can ActiveRecord sub classes be used to hold data from other sources such as Facebook too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, activerecord

I am creating a new application that allow the users to either create content in the local application database or directly on Facebook.

Imagine the user have a CRUD interface for a `Post`. I have a created a model for `Post` that sub classes `ActiveRecord::Base`. Objects of this class has methods for saving the post to the local database.

However, the user is also able to "tick" and option in my application that says "connect to Facebook". When it is checked the content will not be stored in my local database but it will go directly to Facebook Graph API.

The service layer and controller layer is not aware of where the data actually goes. At least this is my idea.

My question is if I can use the same Post class for both local data and Facebook data? Some of the methods in the Post class would not make sense when the post object contains data from Facebook; such as the `save` method.

Does that design seem stupid? Should I create another Post class that is just a normal Ruby class without sub classing `ActiveRecord::Base`? Or are there other better ways?

Comment: When you are using Post with activerecord::base or Post without it, you are definitely going to implement the usual record interface to actions in Facebook, right ?

Answer (score 0):

When designing a class you should make it as lean as possible. A good way to look at it is counting the nouns and verbs that are included in your model. A *post* can be *saved* or *deleted*, but if your save and delete start having logic related to *Facebook* it's a good sign that this should belong to a different class altogether.

One more note related to Facebook: the new guidelines don't allow posting 'pre-written' posts for a user. Meaning that you won't be able to make a post to a users wall without prompting him with Facebook either way.

I don't see any problems with having `Post < ActiveRecord::Base` - that is the standard Rails way and it does look like you should implement the standard ways of storing data to your DB and look into the Facebook posting from another angle.

Answer (score 0):

There are some definite problems with that approach - the first is that you will end up with alot of tight couplings to the Facebook API. I have had tons of grief from the FB API's changing without warning or not working as documented.

Another issue is performance - loading data from FB is often painfully slow even compared to reading from a DB across the wire. It is also prone to outrages (at least in my experience).

I would definitely use "proxy objects" which are stored in your database and regularly hydrated from Facebook instead.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it answered all my questions. Imagine this:But if you were going to show a list in a GUI that is going to display all `page` objects. Then in my application the data would be in a Page object. So you are saying that I should not fill that page object with Facebook data (it inherits from Active Record). Do you have an alternative?

Comment: I definitely depends on the application - if it was an application which displays metrics for facebook pages I would definitely use the data straight from facebook. If it was in like in your case that the user opts into sharing whatever they generate on your app on Facebook I would use an actual DB to store objects even if they are posted to FB. I would then update the records asynchronously with comments etc, when they are actually displayed.